# Regex in PHP: How to get word in last part URL?

Tags: php, regex, url

I have some lines like this:

```
/gtrhr/5435-silent-library
/fghf3/435-silent-librar
/gfgr2gf/8768-silent-lib
```

How to get ONLY words in last part of URL ?

So, the oupout will be:

```
silent-library
silent-librar
silent-lib
```

Thank you !

Comment: Yes, this is correctly tagged. Use a `regex`. Similar to the one in your last question even.

Comment: Don't ask the same question more than once, please.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use something like [strpbrk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php)?

Comment: This is not deduplication !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\-]+$
```

The `$` enforces the match ends with the end of the line.

[See here on Regexr](http://regexr.com/3a4g4).

You could also go for a more general `[a-z][\w\-]+$` but that depends on precisely which characters are valid or not in your inputs.

Comment: Add \d to the second character group.